# MSbuild error while chekout : exited with code 9009

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I am try to chekout my file from TFS using MSBuild script. But I am getting "exited with code 9009"

My code is bellow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
<PropertyGroup>
 <TfCommand>
    &quot;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe&quot;
 </TfCommand>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Build">
 <Exec Command="$(TfCommand) checkout &quot;$/ApplicationSharedServices/release/dev_branch/renderer/bin/MIME.dll&quot;"/>
</Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: probably not related, but why do you have a bin folder under source control?

Comment: do you have a workspace set up for that source control mapping?

Comment: From Visualstudio I have downloaded the files from TFS. Same folders I am using these operations.
Other than that mapping need to provide from MSbuils?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Just TFS's answer, you need to be in the folder that is in your workspace before you run TF.  it might work fine with VS but with MSBuild pure you need to be in the folder.  Now you technically don't need to put the full path when doing the get then.  just MIME.dll.

Just out of curiosity, why are you running an MSBuild TF get command? is this in you automated build? You should start using PowerShell and run a pre-build script to get the info you need.  You could also use Nuget with package restore to get any DLLs needed for compilation.

Cheers,
ET

Comment: Yes, I am writing automated build script using MSBuild.
I have the below requirement
1.Checkout dlls 2. Get latest files 3. compile solutions 4. checkin the dlls from TFS.
If I use TF command in MSbuild script. Is valid right or any other command is there in MSbuild for perform actions on TFS? No third packages.

Comment: Well TFS build does 1 (if in the build definition workspace)/2/3 won't do 4 by default.  Now why do you want to check back in your dlls? Is it because you are actually compiling them and want to push back the new built ones? What are those DLL used for? Are they dependency components for other projects? Have you looked at Nuget for that?

Comment: Yes, I am compiling  and checkin the new dlls(if the code changed ot not).
Those dlls are dependency dlls (our own dlls).
Dll are not a dependency to other project. Those are used in our application only.

Comment: I have posted my entire script in URL : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26585388/msbuild-script-code. please take a look on this

Comment: So lets reposition this question, are you using the TFS Build service? If yes, then you should let it do all the work for you, checkout, build, etc.  And then you can write a powershell script to checkin only the DLL you care about back to TFS.  If not, why not?